# Can you have foreign key constraint without having to create another table?

Tags: python-3.x, database-design, sqlite

I am not quite sure how to word this so I will give an example.  I have a program that reads in it's database tables from user-defined csv files. (I am using SQLite with Python.)

Say we have tables:

**Profile (**
  profile_name  TEXT,
  zoning            TEXT,
  share              REAL 
  PRIMARY KEY (profile_name, zoning), 
**)**

**ProfileAssign (**
  geography      TEXT,
  year                INTEGER,
  profile_name  TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (geography, year),
  FOREIGN KEY geography REFERENCES geography
**)**

Where we want each geography to have an associated zoning profile. Now say we also wanted to ensure that the user doesn't assign a profile that doesn't exist to a geography, i.e. we want to have a foreign key constraint in the **ProfileAssign** table:

**FOREIGN KEY profile_name REFERENCES profile**

Now obviously this cannot happen since profile_name is not the primary key of the Profile table.  My solution has been to create a separate table on which we can create a foreign key reference:

**ProfileListing (**
  profile_name    TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (profile_name)
**)**

Which is quite annoying for the user because not only do they have to define these profiles, they now have to list all of their names in a separate file.  Any ideas how to circumvent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreign keys need to identify a row in the parent table.
This is usually done with the primary key, but any other *unique* key works as well; the only requirement is that the uniqueness is enforced (with a UNIQUE constraint):

```sql
CREATE TABLE Profile (
  profile_name  TEXT UNIQUE,
  zoning        TEXT,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (profile_name, zoning)
);

CREATE TABLE ProfileAssign (
  ...
  FOREIGN KEY profile_name REFERENCES profile(profile_name)
);
```

Comment: Uniqueness isn't required by all DBMSs. It's best to think of FK constraints as subset constraints rather than as references.

Comment: Uniqueness is required by the SQL standard, and by all DBMSes that conform to it. If you're telling me that this is yet another thing that MySQL (which is off topic here) gets wrong, I wouldn't be suprised.

Comment: When you declare a foreign key, it has to reference something, either a different row in the same table or a row in a different table.  However, a data item can function like a foreign key, even if it is not declared as such.  Depending on the source of your CSV files, you might be reading in dirty data.  If so, you are better off putting the data into staging tables with no constraints, and copying the clean data from the staging tables to the real tables.